# Typed Configuration in Functional Test whit XUnit c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I am writing functional tests for my API with XUnit.
I have configured my API using types. Something like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.ConfigureServices(services)
          .Configure<SqlServerData>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SqlServerData)))
          .Configure<SolrData>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SolrData)));
}
```

The problem comes when I try to configure my TestServer of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost class in the same way:

```
  Server = new TestServer(
    new WebHostBuilder()
      .ConfigureServices(services =>
      {
         //SOME STUFF
      })
      .Configure(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SqlServerData)))
      .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
 );
```

I get the following error

> cannot convert from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationSection` to `System.Action<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.IApplicationBuilder>`

Comment: `TestStartup` should inherit from your SUT's `Startup` class. As such, it's completely unnecessary to add this configuration again, in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configure` method is defined in `WebHostBuilderExtensions` class  in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` assembly and its signature is as follows:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder Configure(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder,
  Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
{
    ...
}
```

This means you must pass an action containing an `IApplicationBuilder` implementation instance. Something similar you can find in the `Startup` class in the API you're testing.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
}
```

Other dependencies can also be injected in the `Configure` method, provided they're registered with the DI container you're using. `Configure()` is called by the runtime so you normally don't need to explicitly invoke it.

If what you need is to get an instance of your configuration in the `Configure` method, you can get it (or any other registered dependency) from the `IServiceProvider` instance that is exposed by the `IApplicationBuilder` object of the configuring action you pass to the method:

```
Server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
    .Configure(appBuilder =>
    {
        //get the required service from the appBuilder's ApplicationServices property
        var config = appBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetService<IConfiguration>();

        var section = config.GetSection("YourSection");
        //Use your section here.
    })
    .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
```

However, please be careful because at that point it might be already too late to setup a service. `Configure()` is mostly used to setup the request pipeline. Even though you might have a legit use case to use the configuration in it, you should verify you can't do it in the `ConfigureServices()` method instead.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Very thanks for your response:

Other thing is I needed to add a reference to the Nuget:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions
```

Now I can do something like:

```
Server = new TestServer(
            new WebHostBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {

                services.Configure<SqlServerData>(Configuration.GetSection("SqlServerData"));
                services.Configure<SolrData>(Configuration.GetSection("SolrData"));
            })
            .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
        );
```

Thanks